# Find the most likely element in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

So I have a list of possible values. Some are correct and some are not correct. But they are relatively close together.

```
['POYS499', 'PDY9499', 'POY9499', 'PDYS499', 'PDYS499', 'PDY949']
```

The correct value should be `PDY9499`. Is there a way to do this. A algorithm that was already created to do this.

I know how to do it manually. I will match every character and get the frequency and then create a list from highest to lowest match. Of course you need to ensure the max characters stay the same.

Is there a simpler way?

--edit
Maybe I'm not explaining it correctly. I want a "function" that returns a list with the highest recurring characters in element list item.

So it checks the first character. If it has 5 p's then P is the first character.
Then it checks the second character. 3 D's and 2 O's. So we get so far

```
['PD', 'PO']
```

Then it checks the third character. etc.

Comment: Unclear why it should be `PDY9499`.

Comment: The last string is shorter than the others. Is that correct or a typo?

Comment: The output I want is PDY9499. I have a list of results that are exactly that or close to that. I want to know if there is something that can produce that

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to count the frequency of each character per position in the string. But in your example, it then seems unclear how one should deduce that `PDY9499` is correct, as the character `S`has the same frequency in position 4 as the character `9`.

Comment: thats interesting. But yes that is what I want. In the case you pointed to then I would have the two values added the one with S and the one with 9. I can do this but I was wondering if something exists already so I don't waste time.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Counter from the collections module? I've included an example below:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(['POYS499', 'PDY9499', 'POY9499', 'PDYS499', 'PDYS499', 'PDY949'])
```

Output:

```
Counter({'POYS499': 1, 'PDY9499': 1, 'POY9499': 1, 'PDYS499': 2, 'PDY949': 1})
```

**Edit:** An additional solution that sorts your list is:

```
from collections import Counter
counter_output = Counter(['POYS499', 'PDY9499', 'POY9499', 'PDYS499', 'PDYS499', 'PDY949'])
sorted(counter_output.items(), key =lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
```

Output:

```
[('PDYS499', 2), ('POYS499', 1), ('PDY9499', 1), ('POY9499', 1), ('PDY949', 1)]
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand. I need to get the most likely value based on the list of values. Im not sure the counter approach will help me.